# ggplot2 displaying multiple points for discrete variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show different countries Index scores on the y axis for a metric column in my dataframe(discrete variable) and color the points based on the country.

The snippet of dataframe, test:

| Countries | Metric | Index Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Equity | 99.1 |
| USA | Equity | 6.9 |
| France | Equity | 75.4 |

```
ggplot(test,aes( x= Metric , y= "Index Score", color = Countries)) + 
geom_point()
```

The output currently looks like this:
[all points are on top of each other and not dispersed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gnum.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do `` y = `Index Score` `` , a string is not valid.

Comment: this didn't change the outcome

Comment: @shains So please edit your post and share the data with `dput(test)`.

Comment: @shains Have you noted these are backticks, not single quotes?